# Swift FB app invite showing blank page

Tags: ios, swift, facebook

This only happened on Iphone 9.2 (2 phones tested) but not happening on Iphone 9.1 
I am getting blank page when calling this (no error triggered). It fires up the safari browser but it will only work if I clicked on the blue "safari" button on the right, it will bring me up to the right page with content. Some sort of ad blocker?
Please advice.
Thanks in advance.

```
let content =  FBSDKAppInviteContent()
    content.appLinkURL = NSURL(string: facebookSetting.inviteLink + PFUser.currentUser()!.objectId!)
    content.appInvitePreviewImageURL = NSURL(string: "http://someurl.jpg")
    FBSDKAppInviteDialog.showFromViewController(self, withContent: content, delegate: self)
```

Here is this PInfo

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>fbapi</string>
    <string>fb-messenger-api</string>
    <string>fbauth2</string>
    <string>fbshareextension</string>
    <string>whatsapp</string>
    <string>wechat</string>
    <string>line</string>
    <string>instagram</string>
    <string>fbapi20150629</string>
    <string>https</string>
    <string>http</string>
</array>
<key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
<true/>
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>fb.me</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
        <key>facebook.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>
        <key>fbcdn.net</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>
        <key>akamaihd.net</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

Answer (score 0):

I restart my phones and it worked. Super strange issue.